# Redirect not working on iphone/mobile data

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect to https and then a subfolder.

It works great on my iPhone until I connect to mobile data and clear my browser/cookies. Then I get a connection time out or server stopped responding error from the links in a google search. If I reconnect to the home/office Wi-Fi and the site loads up with out a problem from the same links. the main site is inside a folder.

I have the following code in the htdocs/htaccess and the index.php4 file

htaccess file - to force all pages to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

htdocs/index.php4 file - to redirect the main domain to a subfolder

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://sundenmanagement.com/home1/index.php">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is the meta refresh explicitly using an HTTP URL again? Assuming I am accessing `http://sundenmanagement.com/` first, then you redirect me to the HTTPS version of that first, only to redirect me from there to `http://sundenmanagement.com/home1/index.php`, and then that to its HTTPS equivalent again.

Comment: Hello, I have tried it both ways it is currently https and then I also tried a php redirect. I am thinking it may have something to do with the joomla site because if I type in the address I want I get the same result.
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
header("Location: https://sundenmanagement.com/home1/index.php"); 
exit;
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://sundenmanagement.com/home1/index.php">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: It appears there is an issue with the site itself when using cellular data. if I go to `https://sundenmanagement.com/home1/index.php` the site will still not load then I turn my wifi back on and the site loads... ??

Comment: Maybe your cell provider has DNS or routing issues? Try and verify that the DNS lookup works, and see what a traceroute shows.

Comment: Now i tried updating MySQL to 5.6 and broke it all won’t load on anything.  Holding the provider can put it back to 5.0. A new joomla install won’t run either.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with the site itself. If I type in the address I want I get the same results.

I still can not access the site on mobile data but the site loads up fine when connected to the home/office WIFI.